# How to make a resizing horizontal menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In mew at web design and can't explain it properly, but take a look at the page I created.
http://workspa.webs.com/new/web.html#

Notice how the banner image maintains 100% width and doesnt seem to increase in size when zooming in and out? I want the horizontal menu to do the same, but dont know how. Right now it increase and decreases in size as I zoom in (similar to how the second pic does on my website).
i made the banner behave like that by using:
HTML:

```
<div class="container"><img src="head.jpg" /></div><br/>
```

CSS:

```
.container {width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

.container img { width: 100%;}

but I dont know how that would work for a horizontal menu. I should note that I created a small menu in the left side, and I put a div with the same color to fit 100% of the width because I didnt know how to make the tabs stay at left side if I made the menu 100% width itself.

This is what I have for the menu:
HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul { display: table; width: 100%;}
ul li { list-style-type: none; position: relative; float: left;}
ul li a { background: #444444; color: white; display: block;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;           padding: 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; }
ul li a:hover { background: red; }

#menu { width: 100%; height: auto; background-color: #444444; }
```

Can you help, I hope my explanation is not too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a little help how you could try make it:

http://jsfiddle.net/w7fLT/

add this to your css

```
#menu {
    width:353px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
    ul li { 
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

have fun coding